Can I load SubscriptionStoreView in background to avoid loading screen when it's launched?
I am testing SubscriptionStoreView.
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/subscriptionstoreview
When I present this view with ViewController for the first time, it shows a loading white screen.
        SubscriptionStoreView(
            productIDs: ["id"]
        )
        .subscriptionStoreButtonLabel(.action)
        .storeButton(.visible, for: .restorePurchases)
        .storeButton(.hidden, for: .cancellation)

Is there any way to load it in the background?

The built in views are not required, you can create your own and have the products pre-loaded

Thanks, it seems there is no way to avoid it at the moment, but it is ok I guess.
